# Pi with Arch Linux and OpenCV: errors when running cmake

Tags: archlinux, opencv, software-compilation, shared-libraries, make

I have a Pi running a fresh Arch Linux installation and I want to install OpenCV 3, but I am facing an error that I do not have when installing OpenCV on my other computers. I wrote a script that works on my other Arch computers, 'opencv' installed by pacman is just OpenCV 2 but I want 3:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# Install opencv with extras and contrib from git
# Tested on ArchLinux
HOME_DIR=/home/counter

# Go to home dir
cd $HOME_DIR

# Install all needed dependencies
sudo pacman -S opencv pkg-config gtkglext intel-tbb libdc1394 openexr xine-lib eigen python-numpy python2-numpy cmake mesa mesa-libgl gstreamer gstreamer0.10-base gst-plugins-base-libs v4l-utils ffmpeg protobuf git wget curl
# Install optional dependencies
sudo pacman -S libcl # For coding with OpenCL
sudo ldconfig

# Download all needed files
# It's always slow on first time but when interrupted and started again it's much faster
git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git
git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib.git
git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_extra.git

# Start building
cd $HOME_DIR/opencv
mkdir build
cd $HOME_DIR/opencv/build

cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=$HOME_DIR/opencv_contrib/modules $HOME_DIR/opencv/build -D OPENCV_TEST_DATA_PATH=$HOME_DIR/opencv_extra -D BUILD_opencv_highgui=OFF -D BUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
# -D BUILD_opencv_dnn=OFF on errors with libprotobuf
make -j5

# Install them
echo "Install OpenCV"
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

But when running cmake there occurs an error:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=$HOME_DIR/opencv_contrib/modules $HOME_DIR/opencv/build -D OPENCV_TEST_DATA_PATH=$HOME_DIR/opencv_extra -D BUILD_opencv_highgui=OFF -D BUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
-- Detected version of GNU GCC: 53 (503)
-- Found ZLIB: /lib/libz.so (found suitable version "1.2.8", minimum required is "1.2.3") 
-- Found ZLIB: /lib/libz.so (found version "1.2.8") 
-- Found OpenEXR: /lib/libIlmImf.so
-- Checking for module 'gtk+-3.0'
--   Package 'gtk+-3.0' not found
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h - not found
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h - found
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h - not found
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h - found
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h - not found
-- Checking for module 'libgphoto2'
--   Package 'libgphoto2' not found
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
-- To enable PlantUML support, set PLANTUML_JAR environment variable or pass -DPLANTUML_JAR=<filepath> option to cmake
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2.7 (found suitable version "2.7.11", minimum required is "2.7") 
-- Found PythonLibs: /lib/libpython2.7.so (found suitable exact version "2.7.11") 
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found suitable version "3.5.1", minimum required is "3.4") 
-- Found PythonLibs: /lib/libpython3.5m.so (found suitable exact version "3.5.1") 
-- Could NOT find JNI (missing:  JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH) 
-- Could NOT find Matlab (missing:  MATLAB_MEX_SCRIPT MATLAB_INCLUDE_DIRS MATLAB_ROOT_DIR MATLAB_LIBRARIES MATLAB_LIBRARY_DIRS MATLAB_MEXEXT MATLAB_ARCH MATLAB_BIN) 
-- VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:295 (message):
  No extra modules found in folder: /opencv_contrib/modules

  Please provide path to 'opencv_contrib/modules' folder.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  modules/CMakeLists.txt:7 (ocv_glob_modules)


-- Module opencv_ts disabled because opencv_highgui dependency can't be resolved!
-- 
-- General configuration for OpenCV 3.1.0-dev =====================================
--   Version control:               3.1.0-98-g347ffbb
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Host:                        Linux 4.1.15-3-ARCH armv7l
--     CMake:                       3.4.1
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               Release
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 5.3.0)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):
--     Linker flags (Debug):
--     Precompiled headers:         YES
--     Extra dependencies:          /lib/libwebp.so /lib/libpng.so /lib/libz.so /lib/libtiff.so /lib/libjasper.so /lib/libjpeg.so /lib/libImath.so /lib/libIlmImf.so /lib/libIex.so /lib/libHalf.so /lib/libIlmThread.so gtk-x11-2.0 gdk-x11-2.0 pangocairo-1.0 atk-1.0 cairo gdk_pixbuf-2.0 gio-2.0 pangoft2-1.0 pango-1.0 fontconfig freetype gthread-2.0 gstvideo-1.0 gstapp-1.0 gstbase-1.0 gstriff-1.0 gstpbutils-1.0 gstreamer-1.0 gobject-2.0 glib-2.0 dc1394 avcodec avformat avutil swscale avresample /lib/libbz2.so dl m pthread rt
--     3rdparty dependencies:
-- 
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 core flann imgproc ml objdetect photo video features2d imgcodecs shape videoio calib3d stitching superres videostab python2 python3
--     Disabled:                    highgui world
--     Disabled by dependency:      ts
--     Unavailable:                 cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev java viz
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     QT:                          NO
--     GTK+ 2.x:                    YES (ver 2.24.29)
--     GThread :                    YES (ver 2.46.2)
--     GtkGlExt:                    NO
--     OpenGL support:              NO
--     VTK support:                 NO
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        /lib/libz.so (ver 1.2.8)
--     JPEG:                        /lib/libjpeg.so (ver )
--     WEBP:                        /lib/libwebp.so (ver encoder: 0x0209)
--     PNG:                         /lib/libpng.so (ver 1.6.20)
--     TIFF:                        /lib/libtiff.so (ver 42 - 4.0.6)
--     JPEG 2000:                   /lib/libjasper.so (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     /lib/libImath.so /lib/libIlmImf.so /lib/libIex.so /lib/libHalf.so /lib/libIlmThread.so (ver 2.2.0)
--     GDAL:                        NO
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  YES (ver 2.2.3)
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       codec:                     YES (ver 56.60.100)
--       format:                    YES (ver 56.40.101)
--       util:                      YES (ver 54.31.100)
--       swscale:                   YES (ver 3.1.101)
--       resample:                  YES (ver 2.1.0)
--       gentoo-style:              YES
--     GStreamer:                   
--       base:                      YES (ver 1.6.2)
--       video:                     YES (ver 1.6.2)
--       app:                       YES (ver 1.6.2)
--       riff:                      YES (ver 1.6.2)
--       pbutils:                   YES (ver 1.6.2)
--     OpenNI:                      NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
--     OpenNI2:                     NO
--     PvAPI:                       NO
--     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
--     UniCap:                      NO
--     UniCap ucil:                 NO
--     V4L/V4L2:                    NO/YES
--     XIMEA:                       NO
--     Xine:                        NO
--     gPhoto2:                     NO
-- 
--   Parallel framework:            pthreads
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Use IPP:                     NO
--     Use VA:                      NO
--     Use Intel VA-API/OpenCL:     NO
--     Use Eigen:                   YES (ver 3.2.7)
--     Use Cuda:                    NO
--     Use OpenCL:                  YES
--     Use custom HAL:              NO
-- 
--   OpenCL:                        <Dynamic loading of OpenCL library>
--     Include path:                /home/counter/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Use AMDFFT:                  NO
--     Use AMDBLAS:                 NO
-- 
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.11)
--     Libraries:                   /lib/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.11)
--     numpy:                       /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.10.4)
--     packages path:               lib/python2.7/site-packages
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3 (ver 3.5.1)
--     Libraries:                   /lib/libpython3.5m.so (ver 3.5.1)
--     numpy:                       /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.10.4)
--     packages path:               lib/python3.5/site-packages
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
-- 
--   Java:
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         NO
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
-- 
--   Matlab:                        Matlab not found or implicitly disabled
-- 
--   Documentation:
--     Doxygen:                     NO
--     PlantUML:                    NO
-- 
--   Tests and samples:
--     Tests:                       NO
--     Performance tests:           NO
--     C/C++ Examples:              YES
-- 
--   Install path:                  /usr/local
-- 
--   cvconfig.h is in:              /home/counter/opencv/build
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/counter/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/counter/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I grep for fatal errors:

```
less /home/counter/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log | grep -e "fatal error"
/home/counter/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:37: fatal error: /usr/include/libpng/png.h: No such file or directory
/home/counter/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:28: fatal error: linux/videodev.h: No such file or directory
/home/counter/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:25: fatal error: sys/videoio.h: No such file or directory
/home/counter/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:29: fatal error: ffmpeg/avformat.h: No such file or directory
/home/counter/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:28: fatal error: linux/videodev.h: No such file or directory
/home/counter/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:25: fatal error: sys/videoio.h: No such file or directory
/home/counter/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:29: fatal error: ffmpeg/avformat.h: No such file or directory
/home/counter/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:28: fatal error: linux/videodev.h: No such file or directory
/home/counter/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:25: fatal error: sys/videoio.h: No such file or directory
/home/counter/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:29: fatal error: ffmpeg/avformat.h: No such file or directory
/home/counter/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:28: fatal error: linux/videodev.h: No such file or directory
/home/counter/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:25: fatal error: sys/videoio.h: No such file or directory
/home/counter/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:29: fatal error: ffmpeg/avformat.h: No such file or directory
/home/counter/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:28: fatal error: linux/videodev.h: No such file or directory
/home/counter/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:25: fatal error: sys/videoio.h: No such file or directory
/home/counter/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:29: fatal error: ffmpeg/avformat.h: No such file or directory
```

All examples on how to install OpenCV for the Pi do not set any flag that they run on a Pi and I guess I have installed all dependencies, I do not want to create sym links between libraries to make it work.

Edit: I can install a working opencv with yaourt but not opencv-contrib

Answer (score 1):

I do not know where the error is and still cannot compile it with my script.

But using `yaourt` it works.
You can install [opencv-contrib](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/opencv-contrib/). The original `PKGBUILD` would not let you compile it because the Pi is an armv7h or armv6h architecture. But you can trick it by changing the `PKGBUILD`. Just add `'armv7h' 'armv6h'` to `arch` as shown below and add the other two lines as well. Then it should  compile well.

```
arch=('i686' 'x86_64' 'armv7h' 'armv6h')

# NEON support only for armv7h
[[ "$CARCH" = 'armv7h' ]] && _cmakeopts+=('-D ENABLE_NEON=ON')

# intel-tbb not available for armv6h
[[ "$CARCH" = 'armv6h' ]] && _cmakeopts+=('-D WITH_TBB=OFF')
```

There is the possibility that the compilation will fail, that happened to me on a fresh Arch installation, that was caused by a missing package, maybe have a look at the dependencies at the [arch website](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/testing/x86_64/opencv/) and install all of them.